# My Compound Components and Screen Layouts are in the same directory, is there a better way?

Tags: android, xml, layout, view, custom-component

So I'm making compound components following on from [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCustomViews/article.html#customviews).

I'm thinking it's really messy that my compound component layout xml files live in the same folder as screen layouts, for the sake of separation of interests, neatness, code portability and all that good coding stuff, is it at all possible to put these custom components in their own folder like layout_customviews or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can create android library project which will contain your compound views